# Why is the "source" version given so much importance in Perforce while merging (resolving conflicts to be verbose)?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I don't think I even want to see it. Why do others find it so important ?

[image]

Isn't Base, Target enough for the "resolving  conflicts" aka Merge tool window. What am I missing ? Are people really that bothered about the version before Base i.e. Source ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you have a fundamental misunderstanding about what each of the versions are.  When you merge two branches, almost always you want to keep changes from both branches.  `Base` is the latest common ancestor of the two branches.  `Base->Source` shows what was changed in the branch you're merging from, and `Base->Target` shows what was changed in the branch you're merging to.  To properly resolve a conflict, you need to know what was changed in each branch.

Answer (score 6):

(Some documentation for p4merge at [p4 docs - Merging Files](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/merging_files.html))

When working with a merge conflict, there are four parts to it:

1. The common ancestor that both branches changed
2. Their changes (source)
3. Your changes (target)
4. The final result

[image: p4 merge results]

(You may have an old version of p4merge - the docs show a different wording that may clear up the confusion)

The 'source' is not the revision before, but rather the incoming changes from the merge that someone else made.

Ignoring either your changes or their changes is a possible conflict resolution - many have that as a default "merge, handle conflicts by use mine."  However, this has the distinct possibility of causing regressions of functionality introduced by the other branch (or worse, removing code the other branch is expecting).

For a given code block with a conflict, both your changes *and* their changes are important, and the ancestor of the two gives the appropriate context for what the change was.

Comment: Thanks. One reason I was particularly confused is that right now I am merging changes from my own *developer branch* to the *production branch*. Thus the work seems one dimensional to me - i.e. There is only a single branch (the developer branch in which my changes are present) and I have to merge the changes from this branch to the production branch. But what I failed to understand is that in a generic scenario of merge there might be other changes made to the production branch by others. The reason for this is that I am the only developer working in this module. Thanks for clearing it all up